# Unity:How to find the value of a vector 3 allong a specific axis?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector

For example, you might use something like:

```
 public Vector3 Inertia = new Vector3();
 void Update()
 {
     Inertia += transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * Input.GetAxis("Thrust") ;
     transform.Translate(Inertia * Time.deltaTime);
 }
```

If you want fly a spaceship in a 3D space with all degrees of freedom. Inertia keeps track of momentum in world space while the controls add to it along the axes of the players orientation.

But, now I want to check what the players speed is along his current "forward" axes. How do you extract a value out of a vector3 along a arbitrary axes?

Answer (score 3):

If you have an arbitrary axis (call it `axis`), and an arbitrary vector (call it `vector`) and you want to find the vector component of `vector` in the direction of `axis`, you can do that with just the dot product. (see [vector projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection)).

**Scalar projection**
The component of `vector` in the direction of `axis` is:

```
float component = Vector3.Dot(vector, axis.normalized);
```

Eg: If the axis was the `z` axis, this would be the `z` component of the vector.
The absolute value of `component` is the magnitude of the projected vector.

**Vector projection**
The projection of `vector` onto `axis` is:

```
Vector3 proj = axis.normalized * component;
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to check what the players speed is along his current "forward"

First of all

```
Inertia += transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * Input.GetAxis("Thrust") ;
transform.Translate(Inertia * Time.deltaTime);
```

can simply be written as

```
Inertia += transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Thrust");
transform.position += Inertia * Time.deltaTime;
```

Then you could [`Project`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Project.html) the total `Inertia` vector onto the `transform.forward` vector

> Projects a vector onto another vector.
>
> To understand vector projection, imagine that `onNormal` is resting on a line pointing in its direction. Somewhere along that line will be the nearest point to the tip of vector. The projection is just `onNormal` rescaled so that it reaches that point on the line.
>
> [image]

and then take its [`magnitude`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-magnitude.html)

> Returns the length of this vector (Read Only).
>
> The length of the vector is square root of (`x*x+y*y+z*z`).

Then you can multiply it by the [`Dot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Dot.html)

> For normalized vectors Dot returns 1 if they point in exactly the same direction, -1 if they point in completely opposite directions and zero if the vectors are perpendicular.

```
var forwardSpeed = Vector3.Project(Inertia, transform.forward).magnitude * Vector3.Dot(Interia.normalized, transform.forward));
```

Comment: Your solution always returns a positive value.