# Unity/C#: check velocity before vertical jump?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do you convert rb.velocity into an integer?

I attempted to have `if (rb.velocity < 0)` to then make a jump be able to add to existing momentum without jumps doing nothing if the negative momentum is to high.

Comment: velocity is a [vector](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html). meaning, simplified, it is not just a simple number, but a combination of 3 numbers (one for X,Y and Z). just pick the one you want to compare.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity:How to find the value of a vector 3 allong a specific axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60586769/unityhow-to-find-the-value-of-a-vector-3-allong-a-specific-axis)

Comment: No sorry as its a vector 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the comparison, you just need to do `if (rb.velocity.y < 0)`. This checks if the vertical velocity is less than 0, which is what you really want.

However, I would also recommend you instead set `rb.velocity = 0` every time you jump before applying the jump force (or however you may be making the jump) for consistency.